Settings.gradle include project based on build variant
I have a flutter module and integrated that in my native module. You can see the integration code below. In my native app, I have four flavors "dev", "debug", "uat", "release". Now I want to add flutter module only for "dev" and "debug", how can I achieve this? Though I have tried to catch build variant from settings gradle but the implementation is not working.
settings.gradle:
plugins {
 id "com.gradle.enterprise" version "3.8.1"
}

gradleEnterprise {
 buildScan {
    termsOfServiceUrl = "https://gradle.com/terms-of-service"
    termsOfServiceAgree = "yes"
 }
}

include ':debug'
include ':common-views'
include ':loggedout'
include ':network'
include ':view'
include ':security'
include ':data'
include ':archandroid'
include ':app'

//Below are the code for adding flutter module
setBinding(new Binding([gradle: this]))
evaluate(new File(
    settingsDir.parentFile,
    'Android/flutter_app_module/.android/include_flutter.groovy'
))
include ':flutter_app_module'
project(':flutter_app_module').projectDir = new File('..Android/flutter_app_module')

build.gradle:
implementation project(':flutter')


Each Android build variant defines its own implementation configuration for adding dependencies (docs)
So you can add to the dev and debug variants only by doing
dependencies {
    devImplementation project(':flutter')
    debugImplementation project(':flutter')
}

The associated types that you import will be available in the associated source sets, ie src/dev and src/debug.

What about the import releted issues? Like the "flutter" module will not be available in uat and release build variant, so there will be import related issues?

You'll only be able to access the Flutter classes inside the source sets applicable for the variants that have declared them as dependencies so there won't be clashes

Well, I have made changes like this     devImplementation project(':flutter')
debugImplementation project(':flutter'), but still I am getting those import errors. Can you suggest why that might be happening?

Import them in the correct source sets. Take a good read of the documentation I am linking.

I updated the answer to give some clarity
